# Can I turn off profiling in a portion of python code when invoking cProfile as a script?

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

I want to profile my code, but exclude startup.

Python docs [describe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) how to run cProfile as a script:

```
python -m cProfile [-o output_file] [-s sort_order] (-m module | myscript.py)
```

They also describe how to turn profiling on and off using the python API:

```
import cProfile

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
# ... do something ...
pr.disable()
```

Will it be effective to run `pr.enable()` and `pr.disable()` if I am running cProfile as a module?

Is there an implied "enable" when starting my code that I could disable, or is the `cProfile` object used by the script method not accessible to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `cProfile.Profile` object created when run as a script is not accessible. The next best thing would be to instantiate `cProfile.Profile` in your program as close to the start as possible, and call `disable()` and `enable()` on that instance.

This approach means you should no longer run cProfile as a script; that is, you should remove `-m cProfile` from the command line. Also you will have to add the code to print out the stats at the end of your program, because `-m cProfile` is no longer there to do it automatically for you.